# Search through arrays as an object's properties and return the corresponding key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

Hi guys I am trying to find a more clean and robust way to do this task.

Say I have an object call `total`

```
const total = { 
                toDevice: [{'a':'a'},{'b':'b'},], 
                fromDevice: [{'c':'c'},{'c':'c'},]
               };
```

and assume I Shallow-cloning both the arrays of `toDevice` and `fromDevice` like this

```
const copiedArr = [...total.toDevice, ...total.fromDevice]
```

I get a reference of an object inside this `copiedArr` array.

```
const a = copiedArr[1];
```

then I want to do a search to return the corresponding key for the reference inside the `total` object.

For example, if I search for `a`, it should return string `toDevice`

Here is the solution I came up with

```
Object.keys(total).filter(key => {
  return total[key].indexOf(a) !== -1;
})[0]
```

Don't think this is the best approach. Do you guys have any better solutions?

Comment: `key => total[key].includes(a)`

Comment: And use `find` instead of `filter`

Comment: @diouze good catch!

Comment: because of the way you've written the properties ('a': 'a'), it's hard to say even what you mean when you say searching for "a" should return "toDevice." Is that because a is a key in an element in the array, or a value?

Comment: I thought it matches a because both variables reference the same object in the memory?

Comment: The edited description is clearer. I'll take another look now that I understand the question better. For future reference, one of the best things you can do is to make sure you provide a full, working example of your code so others can run it and see exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it wasn't clear to me from your original question whether you wanted to match keys or values in the child array objects, I wrote one example for each use case:

```js
const total = { 
  toDevice: [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }], 
  fromDevice: [{ c: 3 }, { d: 4 }]
}

const matchKey = (needle, haystack) => (
  Object.entries(total).find(
    ([key, value]) => value.some(item => Object.keys(item).includes(needle))
  ) || []
)[0]

console.log(matchKey('a', total))

const matchValue = (needle, haystack) => (
  Object.entries(total).find(
    ([key, value]) => value.some(item => Object.values(item).includes(needle))
  ) || []
)[0]

console.log(matchValue(4, total))
```

Given your subsequent edit and clarification of the problem, I would suggest something like this:

```js
const total = { 
  toDevice: [{'a':'a'},{'b':'b'}], 
  fromDevice: [{'c':'c'},{'c':'c'}]
}

const a = [...total.toDevice, ...total.fromDevice][1]

const matchObject = (needle, haystack) => (
  Object.entries(haystack).find(
    ([key, value]) => value.includes(needle)
  ) || []
)[0]

console.log(matchObject(a, total))
```

**Notes:**

1. `Object.entries` is more ergonomic than `Object.keys` for this use case.
2. `Array.prototype.find` shortcuts the iteration over the array as soon as a match is found (as opposed to `Array.prototype.filter`, which will always continue to iterate over the entire array).
3. `Array.prototype.includes` is almost always more ergonomic than `Array.prototype.indexOf`.

**Docs:**

[Object.prototype.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't make myself clear. I updated the questions. I meant to match two variables containing the same reference to an object.